# Java GIS and openlayers

Tags: java, scala, gis, openlayers-3

Currently we are working on an existing system that uses C# webserver interacting with OSGEO Mapguide and MS-SQL Server. Displays the map and layers in a JS client app using openlayers.

Mapguide is very slow and we'd like to run on Linux, so I am researching for how to do it using Java or Scala. I'd like to develop a GIS server using Java and client app using JS with openlayers (without mapguide). For now I don't mind wich DB to use (SQL or NoSQL).

Is there a 3rd-party that can help me? An example perhaps.

Comment: If your interested, I'm happy to document my mapserver/apache/std html approach (No JAVA what so ever) but if your not, then I won't

Comment: @JohnSlegers I suspect the Luciad tag isn't very useful. [Let me know if you disagree, though](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350280/burninate-request-luciad-tag?noredirect=1#comment479429_350280)!

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer java based GIS system, the GeoServer which is written in Java would be one of the best choice you can have. It supports various of DB and use OGC WMS as its output and it runs fast at least for me. This works with OL3 naturally and there are many examples from the large user community and detailed tutorials that you can find online. Good luck!